# Add 4 weekdays to the WooCommerce order_date

Tags: php, wordpress, date, woocommerce, strtotime

I want the WooCommerce packing slip to show a pickup date for our staff.  I can't seem to get it to pull from the `order_date`.  It just pulls from today's date.  If I print the packing slip a day after the order was placed, it doesn't show the correct date.

I feel like I have tried everything to add `order_date` to the string but I can't figure it out.

This is what I have used.

```
$var=date('"l, F, jS"', strtotime( '+ 4 weekdays'));
echo $vaI;
```

I want it to just show 4 weekdays from the order date. Not from the date I print the packing slip.

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order_date = $order->get_date_completed(); // get the order date from WooCommerce order object

$var = date('"l, F, jS"', strtotime( $order_date ) + strtotime ( '4 weekdays' ));
```

Comment: Please describe, what did you change and why, to help others understand the problem and this answer

Comment: that doesn't work.  It still just uses the date i print it.  Where in the packing-slip.php should i be putting it?